# Issue with images in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've created a small HTML page, but a strange error I have never seen before is occurring.

On the bottom right of all images, a small white square is appearing.

URL: http://squaretise.com/martin-luther-king

Comment: Which browser? all? also, please provide a JSFiddle instead of a URL to a website. Thanks. :) Edit: I don't see any problem of which you are mentioning in Chrome, here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's your `<embed>` tag. Try hiding it:

```
<embed src="mlk.mp3" width="0" height="0" style="display:none;" />
```

`width` and `height` assume their values are in pixels, so there's no need to put `px` in there.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's your embed mp3 that generated a pause button by default.